# Concatenate arrays inside a tuple in simpler way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a tuple X whose element is 2-D numpy arrays that have same 1st dimension and different 2nd dimension. I want to concatenate those arrays to make 1 big array. For example:

X = (np.array of shape[10,3], np.array of shape[10,5], np.array of shape[10,7]).
I want to make a final array Y that has a shape of [10,15] which is the concatenation of all elements in tuple X.

I did something like this. It works, but I'm asking if there is any shorter/simpler way to do this? Thanks!

```
def concat_arrays(data: tuple) -> np.ndarray:
    final_array = data[0]
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if i > 0:
            final_array = np.hstack((final_array,data[i]))
    return final_array
```

Comment: Okay, you know how you had to write `np.hstack((final_array,data[i]))` instead of just `np.hstack(final_array,data[i])` with a single pair of parentheses? So, you're passing it a tuple. Did you consider what would happen if you passed it a tuple that has more than two items? Can you think of a tuple that you *already have in your program* that would be particularly convenient to pass? Now, what happens if you try that? Also, did you try reading the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It is this simple:

```
def concat_arrays(data: tuple) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.hstack(data)
```

There is no need to iterate through and stack one at a time - that's why you are asked to pass a tuple instead of two separate arguments. (That isn't a real restriction in Python anyway - because `*args` exists - but still.)

But of course, there is no point to writing this, as we could simply use `np.hstack` directly.